# Jquery - find content between span tag and appen

Tags: jquery

My span tag looks like this **`<span itemprop='description'>test123</span>`** what i want to do is read the contents between the tag and add a `<b>Copyright 2013</b>` before the `</span>` tag, so it would look like `<span itemprop='description'>test123<b>Copyright 2013</span>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.append()`:

```
$(function(){
  $('span[itemprop="description"]').append('<b>Copyright 2013</b>');
});
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesnt work here dev10.edisbest.com/test.html

Comment: one more question if instead of hardcode "<b>Copyright 2013</b>"

If i want to read contents of following table including the table tag with class="C1", what do i have to change in "append" ?

<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" class="C1">

Answer (score 2):

```
$('span[itemprop="description"]').append("<b>Copyright 2013</b>");
```

this should fix it, even though i am not sure if the selector is correct

as suggested here's a link to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("span[itemprop='description']").append("<b>Copyright 2013</b>");
```